# How can i use a black and white image to mask an image to another image in python using Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, mask

I am trying to use a black and white image to mask out certain areas of image1 and paste it onto image2 in python using Pillow. I've tried using "PIL.Image.composite(image1, image2, mask)" but it didnt work or i did something wrong.
Sorry that i dont have the code to that anymore,
the only code i have left is

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageOps, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import os
avatars = []

for img in os.listdir():
  if img.endswith(".png") is True:
    avatars.append(img)

#open the images
mask = image.open("./masks/roundmask.png")
avatar1 = Image.open(avatars[0]).resize((128,128))
avatar2 = Image.open(avatars[1]).resize((128,128))

"""
mask the image avatar1 using the mask image and paste it on top of avatar2
"""
end = Image.open("./template/image.png").paste(avatar1, (190,93)).paste(avatar2, (420,38))

end.save("./finished/end.png")
```

[avatar1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u35XI.png)

[avatar2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUOw5.png)

[mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF0qK.png)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAbaZ.png)

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89907/PIL.Image.composite

Comment: Please be more specific. What did not work. What have you tried?

Comment: You question is missing 2 avatar images, a mask image and the expected result image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only guess you were either trying with incompatible image dimensions (they are all slightly different sizes) or you got the modes wrong. Anyway, starting with these 2 input images and this mask:

[image]

this is what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Load images, discard pointless alpha channel, set appropriate modes and make common size
av1  = Image.open('avatar1.png').convert('RGB').resize((500,500))
av2  = Image.open('avatar2.png').convert('RGB').resize((500,500))
mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L').resize((500,500))

# Composite and save
Image.composite(av1,av2,mask).save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

By the way, you can do the same thing on the command line in Terminal with ImageMagick:

```
magick avatar1.png avatar2.png mask.png -composite result.png
```

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, PIL, Pillow, composite, mask, masking, blend.

Comment: thumbs up, this is very helpful, I wonder where I can find more clear tutorial like this.

Comment: @JamesHardcoder I do quite a few, you can see my answers on PIL/Pillow like this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2836621%20%5bpil%5d