# Python PIL Trying to swap square pixel groups between two images

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I have tried this code so much, and I cannot find where the error is (see code below.)

The idea is to take two pictures of the same size and swap square groups of pixels between them, creating two checkerboards.

The code here uses images 400x400 pixels respectively red and green.

The one resulting image, ___OUTPUT_IM_100_POS.png, is as it should. However, ___OUTPUT_IM_100_NEG.png, is a copy of its original form.

I am sure that it is a very newbie mistake, and yet, please...

```
from PIL import Image
# The import below is to be able to always have the right line number when printing messages...
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo


# The function below is used for debugging. It allows always having the line when the message is written.
def pprint(line_number, message):
    # print(end)
    print('L_' + str(line_number) + ': ' + message)


# declare paths
images_path = r'C:\_D_Drive\_pictures\for_asking'
# Declare input images names
input_images_names = [images_path + r'\4_squares_pos.png', images_path + r'\4_squares_neg.png']
# Declare output images and check_size to put in their name
check_size = 100
width = 400
height = 400
output_images_names = [images_path + r"\___OUTPUT_IM_" + str(check_size) + r"_POS.png",
                      images_path + r"\___OUTPUT_IM_" + str(check_size) + r'_NEG.png']
# create two black images of the same size and save them as output_images_names[0] and [1]
adjustable_woven_images = [Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(width, height), color="black"), Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(width, height), color="black")]
adjustable_woven_images[0].save(output_images_names[0], format="png")
adjustable_woven_images[1].save(output_images_names[1], format="png")

red_400x400 = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(width * 1, height * 1), color="red")
red_400x400_pixel_map = red_400x400.load()
green_400x400 = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(width * 1, height * 1), color="green")
green_400x400_pixel_map = green_400x400.load()

# Open the two input images into the output images
output_images = [red_400x400, green_400x400]


# Get pixel maps:
pixel_maps_for_output_images = [output_images[0].load(), output_images[1].load()]
# Declare pixel maps for swap arrays
pixel_maps_for_swap = [pixel_maps_for_output_images[0], pixel_maps_for_output_images[1]]

# Announce start...
pprint(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno, f"Opening\n{input_images_names[0]} and\n{input_images_names[1]}...\n")


# Core function swaps squares...
def swap_square(run_number_given, odd_or_even, i_given, j_given):
    global pixel_maps_for_output_images
    global check_size
    global width
    global height
    global pixel_maps_for_swap
    sq_pos_neg_string = ["POS", "NEG"]

    # Make temp squares if asked for to show process...
    make_temp_squares = False
    if make_temp_squares:
        temp_square_image = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(width, height), color="lightgray")
        temp_map = temp_square_image.load()
        for u in range(width):
            for v in range(height):
                temp_map[u, v] = pixel_maps_for_output_images[0][u, v]
                temp_map[u, v] = (255, 0, 255)
        for u in range(check_size):
            for v in range(check_size):
                temp_map[u + i_given, v + j_given] = pixel_maps_for_swap[0][u + i_given, v + j_given]
        temp_square_image.save(
            images_path + r"\_temp_square_" + str(run_number_given) + "_" + str(check_size) + "_" + sq_pos_neg_string[odd_or_even] + "_" + str(i_given) + "_" + str(j_given) + ".png",
            format="png")

    for k in range(check_size):
        for l in range(check_size):
            if k + i_given < width and l + j_given < height:
                if odd_or_even == 1:
                    pixel_maps_for_swap[0][k + i_given * 1, l + j_given * 1] = pixel_maps_for_output_images[0][k + i_given, l + j_given]
                    pixel_maps_for_swap[1][k + i_given * 1, l + j_given * 1] = pixel_maps_for_output_images[1][k + i_given, l + j_given]
                    pixel_maps_for_output_images[0][k + i_given, l + j_given] = pixel_maps_for_swap[1][k + i_given * 1, l + j_given * 1]
                    pixel_maps_for_output_images[1][k + i_given, l + j_given] = pixel_maps_for_swap[0][k + i_given, l + j_given]
    pprint(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno, f"odd_or_even: {odd_or_even} i:j {i_given}:{j_given} Saved {images_path}\_temp_square_{check_size}_{sq_pos_neg_string[odd_or_even]}_{i_given}_{j_given}.png")
    output_images[0].save(images_path + "\\__run#" + str(run_number_given) + "_" + sq_pos_neg_string[odd_or_even] + "_oe_0.png", format="png")
    output_images[1].save(images_path + "\\__run#" + str(run_number_given) + "_" + sq_pos_neg_string[odd_or_even] + "_oe_1.png", format="png")


run_number = 0
for j in range(0, height, check_size):
    if height - j < check_size:
        pprint(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno, f"WATCH IT: I have a VERTICAL edge here, watch it...")
    for i in range(0, width, check_size):
        if width - i < check_size:
            pprint(getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno, f"WATCH IT: I have a HORIZONTAL edge here, watch it...")
        odd_even = ((int(i / check_size) % check_size) % 2 + (int(j / check_size) % check_size) % 2) % 2
        run_number += 1
        swap_square(run_number, odd_even, i, j)

output_images[0].save(output_images_names[0], format="png")
output_images[1].save(output_images_names[1], format="png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I merged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497922/2836621) answer with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54411453/2836621) answer, to come up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Size of finished images
size = (500,500)

# Create new black image of chess board to use as mask
w, h = 8, 8
mask = Image.new("L", (w,h))
pixels = mask.load()

# Make pixels white where (row+col) is odd
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):
        if (i+j)%2:
            pixels[i,j] = 255

# Scale up to 500x500
mask = mask.resize(size, Image.NEAREST)
mask.save('DEBUG-mask.png')
```

The mask looks like this:

[image]

Code continues from above:

```
# Create two images to merge "chunkily"
lime = Image.linear_gradient('L')
lime = ImageOps.colorize(lime, 'black', 'lime').resize(size)
blue = Image.new('RGB', size, 'blue')
```

Those look like this:

[image]

[image]

```
# Paste blue onto lime with first mask
res1 = lime.copy()
res1.paste(blue, mask)
res1.save('res1.png')

# Paste blue onto lime with inverted mask
res2 = lime.copy()
res2.paste(blue, ImageOps.invert(mask))
res2.save('res2.png')
```

That makes these two:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried the code you sent, and it gives two errors:

res1.paste(blue, mask) # error: Expected type 'tuple[int, int] | tuple[int, int, int, int] | None', got 'Image' instead 

res2.paste(blue, ImageOps.invert(mask)) # error: Expected type 'tuple[int, int] | tuple[int, int, int, int] | None', got 'Image' instead

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkSetchell for an answer that has wiiiiidened my horizon about what I can do with images. I had no idea about the possibility of using masks. And, I would like to be able to do it "by hand". Would you look at my code again and see what I missed, because considering that the one picture end up ok, there should not be much to fix to make the second one ok as well...

Comment: I have now tried the code you sent, and it gives two errors:

res1.paste(blue, mask)  # error: Expected type 'tuple[int, int] | tuple[int, int, int, int] | None', got 'Image' instead 

res2.paste(blue, ImageOps.invert(mask))  # same error

Comment: fixed it:

res1.paste(blue, (0, 0), mask)

mask2 = ImageOps.invert(mask)
...
res2.paste(blue, (0, 0), mask2)